# Выключилась база Postgresql и больше не стартует

Tags: postgresql

Установлен postgresql-10 и крутится база размеров в 2Tb.

```
2022-06-24 07:32:45.960 UTC [1222] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5433
2022-06-24 07:32:45.962 UTC [1222] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "192.168.1.50", port 5433
2022-06-24 07:32:45.962 UTC [1222] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"
2022-06-24 07:32:55.047 UTC [1248] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2022-06-24 07:28:59 UTC
2022-06-24 07:32:55.047 UTC [1248] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
2022-06-24 07:33:03.870 UTC [1248] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2022-06-24 07:33:04.052 UTC [1248] LOG:  redo starts at 593C/91286E8
2022-06-24 07:33:28.005 UTC [1248] WARNING:  will not overwrite a used ItemId
2022-06-24 07:33:28.005 UTC [1248] CONTEXT:  WAL redo at 593C/85C89558 for Heap/INSERT: off 8
2022-06-24 07:33:28.005 UTC [1248] PANIC:  failed to add tuple
2022-06-24 07:33:28.005 UTC [1248] CONTEXT:  WAL redo at 593C/85C89558 for Heap/INSERT: off 8
2022-06-24 07:33:28.065 UTC [1222] LOG:  startup process (PID 1248) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2022-06-24 07:33:28.065 UTC [1222] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2022-06-24 07:33:29.794 UTC [1222] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Можно как-нибудь ее стартануть?

Comment: Там же в логах подсказка `HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.`

Comment: Судя по всему, такое может случиться если на диске ошибка или ещё как-либо повреждён WAL. Можно попробовать сделать ему ресет https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgresetwal.html (у него есть опция `-n` чтобы прогнать в режиме просмотра изменений, без реальных изменений). В любом случае, надеюсь у тебя есть бэкап (или реплики), потому что если WAL повреждён из-за отказа диска, проблем может быть куда больше

Comment: Лог то я внимательно прочитал, уже восстановился с бекапа. Но надо ее стартануть, чтобы вытащить данные от последнего бекапа до падения. 
Спасибо за совет!